# нужен кластер

Tags: кластер

Нужен доступ к кластеру на нужное мне время. Мне нужно чтобы на нем была установлен .Net 4.0 и чтобы там была винда выше XP 64 бита. Чем мощнее кластет, тем лучше. Распараллеливание вычислений мне не нужно. Кто может помочь?

Comment: "Распараллеливание вычислений мне не нужно". Вам нужен Windows High Availability кластер ?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам поможет облако (например Azure)

Comment: Опишите подробнее.

Comment: Подробнее тут: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd163896.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Походу вы не совсем понимаете что такое кластер. Если вам не нужно распараллеливание вычислений, какой профит вы извлечете из кластера, кроме как надежности? Но при этом, вы пишите, что нужно "Чем мощнее кластет, тем лучше". Может лучше посмотреть в сторону высокопроизводительных дедиков или облаков?